# Render Django template with POST data on AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, vue.js, axios

**OBJECTIVE:**

When user is inactive for 5 minutes, my base.js file will send an ajax request to the server, server will flush all session data. I got everything right till here. Further after logging the user out, I want to display a page saying you have been logged out, with some custom data ( eg: user name) which I will be sending to that page via POST method.

I cannot use window.location(url) because in doing so I can only send data with GET method.

**AJAX code in VUE Axios :**

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'ajax/logout/',
    data: { },
    responseType: 'json', 
  })

  .then ( function (response){
      console.log('AJAX success');

  })

  .catch ( function (error){
    console.log('ajaxLogout error');
  });
```

**Django view looks like :**

```
def ajaxLogout(request):
    return JsonResponse ({"success":1} )
```

Comment: Er, no you don't. Why would you want to do that? Ajax is now handling the return value from the Django view; returning a redirect would have no effect. Your comment about why you can't use `window.location` makes no sense. And if you want to redirect, why are you using Ajax at all?

Comment: Is rendering template through AJAX a bad practice? 
Is there any other way to render a template other then forms?
How can I pass parameters {var1: 'xx', var2:'yy'} to a view when calling a url from JS through window.location?

If user is inactive for few minutes I make ajax call to django server, server then deletes session data and WANTS to redirect to homepage. How can this be done?
Thanks

Comment: No rendering a template is fine. But that's not what you asked, you asked about how to redirect. If you want to redirect to the homepage, then use window.location after you've logged them out via Ajax.

Comment: Is there any other way to render a template other then from FORM-action

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: If you are on page1. You want to go on page2. You will create a form on page1 <form action="/page1/" > with a submit button.  once submit button is clicked, django page1 view will redirect you to new page2 {render new html} . 

Is there a way to call a django view page1 without using a form in html

Comment: I still don't understand. A view is called from a URL, it has absolutely nothing to do with "using a form in HTML".

Comment: Is form the only way to submit POST data

Comment: This is bizarre. No, you can use Ajax to send POST data, using the `data` object which you left empty in your code above.